# How do I stop these divs from overlapping?

Tags: css, html

I have three divs, within a content div.

Container width 70%.
Within that I have
 -Left, width 20%.
 -Content, width 60%.
 -Right, width 20%.

I would like container to take up 70% of the page's width, and the inner ones (left, content, and right) to take up 20%, 60% and 20% of the container div.

I have tried other questions on here, I have tried Google, but can't seem to find the right answer. Please help me stop them from overlapping.

[image: Maximized Browser]

But when I re-size the browser, the divs overlap. Like this:

[image: Re-sized Browser]

Here's the relevant CSS code:

```
#container{
    width: 70%;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 600px;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: after reaching their min-width, they can't shrink any further which causes overlapping. only way with using min-width is preventing the user to resize after a certain amount :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the `min-width` from your CSS! And give `min-width` to the container with `margin: auto` to make it center.

Try this CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Check out fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UaqU7/2/

Answer (score 4):

Take out the min-width CSS.

Once the window width gets below a certain size, those elements have no choice but to overlap.  Let's say your window is 1000px; then the container will be 700px.  But with the min widths, the divs in the container are already at 1000px, overflowing the container.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of giving **min-width** of child DIV's you can give it to `#container`. Write like this:

```
#container{
    width: 70%;
    min-width:1000px;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/yLVsb/

Answer (score 2):

You need to take out the `min-width` from your CSS.

When the page is sized smaller the `min-width` stops it from shrinking any further. Thus causing the overlap.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fiddle its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/r42hH/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, if you want a min width, set it on the container

http://jsfiddle.net/VBSYu/1/

```
#container{
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
#left {
     float: left;
     width: 20%;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
}​
```