# stop floated div at specific min-width instead of overlapping

Tags: html, css

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/test12/QrQ2L/)

To put it short.. The whole page is dynamic. Coded to decrease in size until a min width. The custom code begins after #contentLIVE.

The solution i request is allowing the blue div to sit flush on the right of the container and stop after the min-width is set. If you increase the window size past the min-width. The blue div sits flush, but as soon as you hit the min width it continues to move.

blue div

```
#black {width:20px;height:59px;background-color:blue;z-index:2;
position:relative;float:right;margin-right:80px;}
```

Comment: "the blue div". You have *three* blue divs in there. It would be clearer if you coloured the divs differently.

Comment: Jonathan: I went ahead and changed the colors to a more clearer and understandable setup.  Hope that differentiates due to a monitor problem and such..width:20px;height:59px

Comment: Search is great : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991478/how-do-i-stop-these-divs-from-overlapping