# How to fix overlapping issue in the Qweb reports?

Tags: report, odoo, overlapping

I am developing a couple of reports and I ran into an overlapping issue in the header and footer area. I read a couple of similar posts on this topic (downgrade wkhtmltopdf, edit the paper margins/header spacing) but none of them worked for me. Can anyone give me advice on how can I fix this, I am currently using Odoo version 14. The overlapping doesn't occur only for tables but also for regular div elements with the bootstrap class row.

Paper Format:

```
    <record id="paperformat_report_quotation_models_contract" model="report.paperformat">
        <field name="name">European A4</field>
        <field name="default" eval="True"/>
        <field name="format">A4</field>
        <field name="page_height">0</field>
        <field name="page_width">0</field>
        <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
        <field name="margin_top">50</field>
        <field name="margin_bottom">32</field>
        <field name="margin_left">0</field>
        <field name="margin_right">0</field>
        <field name="header_line" eval="False"/>
        <field name="header_spacing">38</field>
        <field name="dpi">90</field>
    </record>
```

I have no left or right margin in order to place two images in the top right corner of the header but I have created a custom CSS class that I use for assigning margins for the content of the page.

```
.contract_paper {
margin: 0 25mm;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

HTML element that is overlapping

```
 <div class="row contract_space_text">
        <div class="col-12">
              <span>
                   Some text.
              </span>
        </div>
 </div>

.contract_space_text {
padding-top: 14px;
}
```

Custom made document layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<data>

    <template id="contact_header_footer">

        <div class="header">
        </div>


        <div class="article" t-att-data-oe-model="doc and doc._name" t-att-data-oe-id="doc and doc.id"
             t-att-data-oe-lang="doc and doc.env.context.get('lang')">
            <t t-raw="0"/>
        </div>


        <div class="footer">
        </div>

    </template>
</data>
</odoo>
```

[Overlapping Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uapcj.png)

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide code like html, css and else

Comment: I added some code, tell me if you need more information about the issue @KarambirSingh.

Comment: Try overflow: hidden

Comment: I tried adding overflow: hidden (with and without !important) in the contract_paper CSS class but that did not work @KarambirSingh.

Comment: First check what thing is overlapping then add overflow: hidden to that.

Comment: Or just find what is overlapping and send me HTML and css code for it

Comment: I added that Html element that is overlapping @KarambirSingh and also tried adding the overflow: hidden attribute it did not solve the issue.

Comment: @Bojan if you define your own header then you should replace the default header. That's why it is overlapped. Inside the <div class="body" > you can give <div class="header"></div> or if you don't want the default header to be visible then you can set top margin to zero in your code. And also when you're giving same id to several reports then it collapses the details while downloading the report.

Comment: @Saks_here I am calling my own custom-made layout and I have placed also my own custom-made header and footer so that the default header or footer are not included.

Comment: Have you tried the code i commented last? When i had the same problem as yours i solved it by the way i commented last. Let me know whether it works for you or not. @Bojan

Comment: @Saks_here I tried replacing the existing header and footer with xpath but did not work. I am not sure where the <div class="body"> needs to be placed because I never used it before does it need to be placed as the main div element and inside it goes the header, article, and footer or needs to be placed somewhere else? I have not given the same id to several reports so that might not be the issue.

Comment: @Bojan, I could help you with only two options for that case. Try setting top margin to zero. The next one, i gave it as an answer.

Comment: @Saks_here I am using my own custom-made layout you can see above, in this case, I don't need to replace anything but I did it anyway and it did not solve the issue. Also tried setting the top margin of the paper format to 0 with and without the xpath and the style did not change.

Comment: To avoid overlapping of div elements you may go through the link given below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991478/how-do-i-stop-these-divs-from-overlapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by increasing and decreasing the top margin and header spacing of the report's paper format.

Thanks to these links and the help of the above users I managed to fix this issue.

```
   <record id="paperformat_report_quotation_models_contract" model="report.paperformat">
        <field name="name">European A4</field>
        <field name="default" eval="True"/>
        <field name="format">A4</field>
        <field name="page_height">0</field>
        <field name="page_width">0</field>
        <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
        <field name="margin_top">52</field>
        <field name="margin_bottom">32</field>
        <field name="margin_left">0</field>
        <field name="margin_right">0</field>
        <field name="header_line" eval="False"/>
        <field name="header_spacing">40</field>
        <field name="dpi">90</field>
    </record>
```

[Custom header overlaps with the body of the report.](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/custom-header-div-class-header-overlaps-with-report-body-div-class-page-in-custom-sales-order-report-91294)

[Header overlaps the body of the report, table example.](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-fix-overlapping-header-printout-81617)

[Header is overlapping with the reports body, useful advice.](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/company-address-is-overlapping-with-shipping-address-in-invoice-pdf-odoo-v13-community-edition-160207)

[Header has overlapped the body of the report, another useful advice.](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/header-overlapping-with-body-in-partner-ledger-report-118709)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="sample_id" inherit_id="module. id_name">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']" position="replace">
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```